# What does a `Model` class look like that has a relation?

Tags: swift, postgresql, fluent, vapor

Using [Vapor](http://vapor.codes) I want to store a relationship to children. I haven't been able to find any examples of what the class should look like and I'm just guessing on what to do. Can anyone provide an example of a class that has a relationship to a list of other `Model` objects?

```
import Vapor
import Fluent
import Foundation

final class Store: Model {

    // MARK: - Model
    var id: Node?
    var exists: Bool = false
    var locationIDs: [Node] = [] // No idea if this is right

    var name: String

    init(name: String, locationIDs: [Node] = []) {
        self.id = nil
        self.name = name
        self.locationIDs = locationIDs
    }

    init(node: Node, in context: Context) throws {
        id = try node.extract("id")
        name = try node.extract("name")
//      ???
    }

    func makeNode(context: Context) throws -> Node {
        return try Node(node: [
            "id": id,
            "name": name
//          ???
        ])
    }

    static func prepare(_ database: Database) throws {
        try database.create( "stores" ) { creator in
            creator.id()
            creator.string("name")
//            creator.id("", optional: false) // ???
        }
    }

    static func revert(_ database: Database) throws {
        try database.delete("stores")
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you read this https://vapor.github.io/documentation/fluent/relation.html?

Comment: Yes, I did, it doesn't give an example of how the property looks in the 'child'. I think I found the issue, it added a _ between the capital letters. Kind of odd... but it's working for me now with my changes. I'll make this question a little better and add my solution.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my implementation of a User and Group relationship.  A user belongs to a group and group has many users, so a simple 1 -> Many relationship.

```swift
final public class User: Model {
  public var id: Int?
  var emailAddress: String
  var username: String
  var groupId: Int

}

extension User {
  var group: Parent<User, Group> {
    return parent(\.groupId)
  }
}


final public class Group: Model {
   public var id: Int?
   var name: String
}

extension Group {
   var users: Children<Group, Users> {
      return children(\.groupId)
   }
}
```

Many <-> Many are similar but use a pivot table in the middle of the relationship.